# How to convert a HTML file to PDF (with colors)

Tags: pdf, convert

I have a HTML file that is using a style.css and has colors, ex.:

```html
<font style="background-color: red; color: white;"> FOO </font>
```

How can I "export" this local file on my Ubuntu 12.04 to a PDF? (the look and color should stay the same). I tried ex.: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -> print to PDF, but it didn't preserve the colours. I tried `htmldoc` with the `--color` option.. but it's the same problem..

It would be great to do this via the command line.

Comment: Related: [Web page to PDF converter](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/35963/3474)

Comment: Just open it in a browser and right click and save page as pdf

Comment: @Harley That option is not available on all browsers and all platforms. I'm an Ubuntu 18 and that option doesn't show up in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: hmmm., ok, yeah I use Opera

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Open your html file in LibreOffice Writer and then, under `File` in the menu, choose `export to PDF`. That's it.

If you prefer the command line, take a look at [Convert HTML Page To a PDF Using Open Source Tool - Linux / OS X / Windows](http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/html-to-pdf-freeware-linux-osx-windows-software/).

The software can be installed using `sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: I think this can be automated on the command line as well with some efforts. :)

Comment: @gertvdijk,  That is beyond my competence. I've never used LibO via CLI.

Comment: There is this, wkhtmltopdf, as well but I have no experience of it: http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/html-to-pdf-freeware-linux-osx-windows-software/

Comment: Please post wkhtmltopdf as ANSWER, it resolved the problem

Comment: @gaskopeter, done as requested by editing the answer.

Comment: libre office actually gave better results than `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: This is a non-solution because LibreOffice's formatting pretty much butchers everything, I lose colors, layout. Using LibreOffice 6.0.7.3

Answer (score 26):

### Webkit HTML to PDF: [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/):

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

[Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/html-to-pdf-freeware-linux-osx-windows-software/) a nixCraft tutorial (updated on 2017).

The latest version is headless (does not require X server).

**Another possibility**: [**phantomjs**](http://phantomjs.org) is a magic headless web browser, also based on webkit html.
It can export a page as PDF among other things.

Comment: On OS X: `brew install Caskroom/cask/wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: On Windows it is available on `scoop` or download the official binaries from the site

Answer (score 14):

[WeasyPrint](http://weasyprint.org/) seems promising. I tried `wkhtmltopdf` and although it renders things in an acceptable way, it doesn't render everything properly and it creates pdfs that take many seconds to open!

Install

```
pip install weasyprint
```

Run

```
weasyprint mypage.html out.pdf
```

As an extra it might be helpful to alter the CSS if you want to get the browser view and PDF to look identical.

```
/* For converting to PDF */
body {
  width: 210mm; /* A4 dimension */
}
@page {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have just tried to install `weasypeasey` but didn't work.. Maybe you could help? :) First I did this: `apt-get install python-dev python-pip python-lxml libcairo2 libpango1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libffi-dev shared-mime-info` and then installing pip with `pip install weasypeasy` but gets this error:  `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement weasypeasy`

Comment: @clarkk my bad. It's actually `weasyprint`. So `pip install weasyprint`

Comment: `weasyprint` is good but about 15 times slower than `wkhtmltopdf` as I recall, so it was not suitable for us to generate reports on demand for our clients.  `wkhtmltopdf` can be persuaded to do a good job even for complex reports... with some considerable effort!

Comment: Awesome it preserves the css and is awesome..

Answer (score 3):

**[Web2PDFConverter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web2pdfconverter/bkanhckocooacphbnclgcndnpfpoppdk?hl=en)** extension for Chromium or Chrome convert any webpage to PDF.

Or, you can just only use this site: **http://pdfcrowd.com/**. For local files: **http://pdfcrowd.com/#convert_by_upload**

Comment: using Firefox+cmd line would be better:P

Comment: @gaskopeter http://pdfcrowd.com/#convert_by_upload - open it in Firefox

Comment: math equations are not converted, one must use printable version

Answer (score 3):

You may try to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and some code, example using [rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js):

```
phantomjs rasterize.js http://example.com/
```

---

Or use NodeJS [`html-pdf` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) (see [GitHub](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf), install via: `npm install -g html-pdf`) as suggested in the comment. Usage:

```
html-pdf http://example.com/ example.pdf
```

Comment: There is a ready to use NodeJS npm package: [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) — HTML to PDF converter that uses phantomjs.

Comment: I could not install it with npm due to missing phantomjs-prebuild (which could not propperly be installed due to access rights, even with root)

Answer (score 2):

Try [Dompdf](http://dompdf.github.io/) (check the [source code at GitHub](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)) which is an HTML to PDF converter. This library is very easy to use, and also very easy to install. Using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) you can set it up pretty fast.

Requirements: PHP 5.0+ (5.3+ recommended), DOM extension, GD extension

Example PHP code:

```php
<?php
// somewhere early in your project's loading, require the Composer autoloader
// see: http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 
// disable DOMPDF's internal autoloader if you are using Composer
define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', false);
 
// include DOMPDF's default configuration
require_once 'vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
 
 
$htmlString = '';
ob_start();
include('html_to_dpf.html');
$htmlString .= ob_get_clean();
 
 
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($htmlString);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried [WeasyPrint](http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) as was suggested by others. It does not convert well in many pages, and in some pages it just fails with an error.

The following Firefox addon works for me. Firefox 55. It says Windows only but it does work on Ubuntu.

[FireShot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/)